# normalize data in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-normalization

I want to do normalization on data that I have

I wrote the following code but it always fill the db with 0s and it shows the following error message. Fatal error: Uncaught exception you have an error in your sql syntax

```
 // normalizaiton 
$queryNorm0= $this->db->query("SELECT score from score where customer_id =".$customer_id." ");
foreach ($queryNorm0->rows as $scoreV)
{
    $scoreValue= $scoreV['score'];

    $queryNorm= $this->db->query(" SELECT MIN(`score`) as mins, MAX(`score`) as maxs FROM score WHERE customer_id= ".$customer_id."");
if($queryNorm->num_rows > 0)
{
$normValue= ($scoreValue - $queryNorm->row['mins'])/ (($queryNorm->row['maxs']) - ($queryNorm->row['mins']) );  
    $queryNorm2= $this->db->query("insert into score set normalized= ".$normValue." WHERE score= ".$scoreValue."");
}
}
```

any help?

Comment: You either have a syntax error or you fill your database with `0`s, which is it? And post the error if there is any.

Comment: What error message do you get? How are we supposed to help you if you don't tell us what the problem is

Comment: @user2148116 This is most definitely not an error message, as it contains just as much information as before. Debug your system and add a *meaningful* error message.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated*

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $customer_id='Your_Customer_Id';
    $query = "SELECT score from score where customer_id =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $customer_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = $res->fetch_all();;
```

This code is using prepared statement. It is more safe and ensures that you will not escape your query. The problem in your code was that the double-quotes you were using were escaping your query. That's where the error was coming from. Have a look also in this link for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Your code has 2 problems. First of all your double-quotes escape your query so you get the error. Second your code is vulnerable to sql-injection (read about this) I provide you a right way to execute your first query. Read my code and do your second query like that also.